# Does Ninject automatically inject non-bound classes?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private MyClass _class;

   public MyController(MyClass class)
   {
       this._class = class;
   }
}

public class MyClass
{
      // stuff
}
```

My Ninject is hooked up to inject classes that implement `IController` (`Controller` class does so). But, I did not bind `MyClass` to anything, yet `Ninject` is still injecting `MyClass` into `MyController`.

I guess my question is, why does it inject something that I didn't bind to anything? Does Ninject run off an find the class with the signature `MyClass`? I assume this behavior would be different if my constructor required a `MyBaseClass` and I have two classes in my assembly that inherit from `MyBaseClass`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565380/disable-implicit-binding-injection-of-non-explicitly-bound-classes-in-ninject-2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ninject V1, ImplicitSelfBinding was a top-level config setting (which defaulted to true IIRC).

In V2, the implicit self binding behavior you observe is more deeply wired in (though there are ways of switching it off -- like most bits of Ninject, it's very granular and minimal). In V2, the default behavior is that self-bindings for concrete types are always generated if no other binding is present. The only time you typically do a `Bind<Concrete>().ToSelf()` is to customise the binding, e.g., to do a `.InSingletonScope()`.

See this [answer by @Remo Gloor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565380/disable-implicit-binding-injection-of-non-explicitly-bound-classes-in-ninject-2) for a way to turn it off in V2+.

Go do a grep in the source right now for ImplicitSelfBinding this instant - it's far easier to read than people rabbiting on though!

Also dont forget to have a look at `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` and tests on ninject.org for arranging implicit `Bind()`ing of `I*X*` to `*X*`

(As Steven alluded to, Ninject would not self bind if you changed your `MyClass` class to be `abstract`.)