# Disable implicit binding/injection of non explicitly bound classes in Ninject 2+

Tags: ninject, ninject-3

If you request an unbound object from NInject, then the default behaviour is (if a suitable constructor is available) appears to be to create an instance of the appropriate object.

I'd like to disable this behaviour (I had a difficult to debug issue because something was auto-bound instead of picking up my custom binding in a module).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846839/does-ninject-automatically-inject-non-bound-classes/3847976#3847976) hints that it is possible, but I'm unable to find the answer from the NInject wiki.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the `SelfBindingResolver` from the kernel components after creation:

```
kernel.Components.RemoveAll<IMissingBindingResolver>();
kernel.Components.Add<IMissingBindingResolver, DefaultValueBindingResolver>();
```

Answer (score 9):

The following is a better, more direct way of removing the `SelfBindingResolver`, without assuming that the `DefaultValueBindingResolver` is the only other `IMissingBindingResolver` component:

```
kernel.Components.Remove<IMissingBindingResolver, SelfBindingResolver>();
```

It's possible the `Remove<T, TImplementation>()` method was only added in a recent version of Ninject, but this works for me using Ninject 3.2.2.0.